# How to Track system shutdown reason?

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a windows application there i need to find exact reason for system shutdown.How can i track that a computer is shut off by power cutoff?? Is there any variable in system environment which tells us how system got shutdown??

Comment: If you want just the application shutdown reason, I would advise you to read this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9shkfdd.aspx#Anchor_0 however if it's the actual computer itself that you want to track then this may not be sufficient.

Comment: I want to get reason when it is shut off by power cut off,if there any system variable or something which holds this value.

Comment: And what exactly is going to power the machine to tell you that it has been shut down by a power failure?

Comment: @DomSinclair : Windows logs a [**Kernel Power (ID 41)**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2028504) event in the event log the next time it starts after a sudden crash. If all BugCheck* variables are set to `0` then it has most likely been shutdown by a sudden loss of power _(for example a power cutoff, or if you held down the computer's power button)_. The BugCheck* variables are only set if Windows was able to recognize a problem that caused it to shutdown.

Comment: Thanks @DomSinclair  for your valuable answer. Can you tell me how can I check all BugCheck variable are set to Zero?

Comment: I wrote the answer, not Dom Sinclair. I just pinged him to inform that there actually is a way of checking it. Doing `@namehere` in Stack Overflow will notify the person called `namehere` that someone has written a comment to them.

Comment: Sorry for that mistake.Thanks @Visual Vincent for your valuable answer.

Comment: That's okay, we all make mistakes sometimes :). Every piece of information that you need can be found in the [**Windows Event Log**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer), which [**can be read from Visual Basic**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6b9a7h8(v=vs.100).aspx). The only thing now is that you just gotta figure out what Event IDs to look for. As I said in my comment above, ID 41 is the Event ID for a sudden system reboot.

Comment: @Visual Vincent,Can you tell me how can I check all BugCheck variable are set to Zero?

Comment: I'll write an answer shortly to how you can read an Event Log event and its data...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small example of locating all the `Kernel Power` events which has the `BugCheckCode` set to `0`:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim EventLogInstance As New EventLog("System") 'Open the "System" event log.

    For Each Entry As EventLogEntry In EventLogInstance.Entries 'Iterate through all entries.
        If GetEventID(Entry.InstanceId) = 41 AndAlso _
            (Entry.ReplacementStrings(0) = "0" OrElse Entry.ReplacementStrings(0).Length = 0) Then 'Checks if the "BugCheckCode" is set to 0.
            'If GetEventID() returns 41 then we know that the entry is of type "Kernel Power".

            ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {Entry.TimeGenerated.ToString("yyyy\/MM\/dd  hh:mm:ss"), Entry.Message})) 'Add the entry's date, time and error message to a ListView.
        End If
    Next
    ListView1.Sort() 'Sort the listview (here, sorting order is set to Descending).
End Sub

Private Function GetEventID(ByVal InstanceId As Long) As Long 'A function for getting the ID of an event.
    Return InstanceId And &H3FFFFFFF
End Function
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

More information can be found in:

- [**How to: Read Event Log Entries**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6b9a7h8(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [**EventLog Class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Well I honestly never knew that, plus one for teaching me today's new nugget of information.